# ROSJAVA : Implementing geometry_msgs.Vector3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How do I code the function toRawMessage when I implement geometry_msgs.Vector3 ?

Currently the structure of my class is as shown below. Is there any documentation.

public class Vector3_self implements geometry_msgs.Vector3 {

```
public double x,y,z;

@Override
public RawMessage toRawMessage() {
    
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public double getX() {
    
    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return x;
}
```

But when I try to publish an Imu value using this class, I get the null exception error:

Code:

protected void loop() throws InterruptedException {

```
  sensor_msgs.Imu imu_accel = publisher.newMessage();
    
      
     accel_values.setX( 5.0 ); // [ where accel_value is  defined as public  Vector3_selg accel_values = new Vector3_self() ];  
     accel_values.setY( 6.0 );
     accel_values.setZ( 7.0 );
         
     imu_accel.setLinearAcceleration(accel_values);
     publisher.publish(imu_accel);


     sequenceNumber += 10;
     Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
```

Error:

Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-6" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.ros.internal.message.ValueField.getSerializedSize(ValueField.java:76)
at org.ros.internal.message.MessageImpl.getSerializedSize(MessageImpl.java:452)
at org.ros.internal.message.MessageImpl.serialize(MessageImpl.java:459)
at org.ros.internal.message.DefaultMessageSerializer.serialize(DefaultMessageSerializer.java:30)
at org.ros.internal.message.DefaultMessageSerializer.serialize(DefaultMessageSerializer.java:26)
at org.ros.internal.transport.OutgoingMessageQueue.writeMessageToChannel(OutgoingMessageQueue.java:79)
at org.ros.internal.transport.OutgoingMessageQueue.access$100(OutgoingMessageQueue.java:38)
at org.ros.internal.transport.OutgoingMessageQueue$Writer.loop(OutgoingMessageQueue.java:56)
at org.ros.concurrent.CancellableLoop.run(CancellableLoop.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43017/rosjava-:-implementing-geometry_msgs.vector3/) by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why are you trying to manually implement a message? Everything is generated automatically and you simply need to use a message factory to get an instance. See the rosjava docs: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pickman](https://answers.ros.org/users/24593/pickman/) on 2016-08-06**:
This links now leads to a missing page. Where could I find the new documentation?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also first tried to implement a geometry_msgs.Vector3, which seemed an intuitive solution at the time. And implementing a Vector3 led me to wonder about implementing a RawMessage. And that led me here, which provided enough of a hint to create the following solution for rosjava 0.1.6.

```
/*
 * Initialization within onStart()
 */ 

String pubTopic = "/turtle1/cmd_vel";
String pubType = Twist._TYPE;
final Publisher<Twist> publisher =
    connectedNode.newPublisher(pubTopic, pubType);

/*
 * To create and publish each message (e.g., inside a loop)
 */

Twist cmd = publisher.newMessage();

Vector3 linear = cmd.getLinear();
linear.setX(1);
linear.setY(0);
linear.setZ(0);

Vector3 angular = cmd.getAngular();
angular.setX(0);
angular.setY(0);
angular.setZ(1);

publisher.publish(cmd);
```

---

Originally posted by [bradknox](https://answers.ros.org/users/11146/bradknox/) with karma: 101 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1